# Connection Pooling in Multi Threaded Java Program

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, connection-pooling

I have a java process which is multi threaded using ExecutorService (15 threads). Each thread calls stored procedure to insert data to table, my connection to be pooled across 15 threads so that I could see multiple commits on the table at the same time, but i only see one connection established for one active thread even through 15 threads are ready and waiting.

Tried using the below code to establish connection and pooled across all threads

```
Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

DataSource oracleDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

ObjectPool objectPool = new GenericObjectPool();

DataSourceConnectionFactory datasourceConnectionFactory = new DataSourceConnectionFactory(oracleDataSource);

PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(datasourceConnectionFactory, objectPool, null, null, false, true);

objectPool.setFactory(poolableConnectionFactory);

PoolingDataSource datasource = new PoolingDataSource(objectPool);
```

but it didn't work still. Still my threads are using only one connection and other threads are waiting for the active one to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate the connection to the DB in a class and create a pool of objects of this class yourself.

Example

```
class Connection {
//  your DB connection specific stuff
public void open() {
//  open connection
}

public void close() {
// close connection
}

public void isOpen() {
//  is the connection being opened by any thread already
}
}
```

Once you have this, create a thread safe method which will return the next available connection object to any requesting thread.

```
class ConnectionController {
public Connection getConnection() {
//  return the next available connection object by checking which 
//connection object is not open by checking return value of isOpen
}
}
```

Make sure you close the connection once you are done!
Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate when you say pool of connection objects.